# How to display html in a shortcode

Tags: shortcode

How do you display or process HTML in a wrapped shortcode ?

`[myshortcode]<div class="map"></div>[/myshortcode]`

my shortcode code is

```
function myshortcode_sc($atts, $content = null) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'col' => 'left',
    ), $atts ) );

$output =  '<div class="span' . esc_attr($col) . '">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';  

return $output;

}
add_shortcode("myshortcode", "myshortcode_sc");
```

is there another function at the return to allow for $output to process the HTML and not just display it as text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try replacing

```
. do_shortcode($content) .
```

with
`.$content.` ?

Source: http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2009/02/02/mastering-wordpress-shortcodes/

Answer (score -2):

my solution : `do_shortcode(html_entity_decode($content))`
But not working with ' & " :/