# JetEngine Query Builder - order by value from repeater

Tags: query, order

Using Wordpress JetEngine UI. I have:

- a JetEngine Post Type named "Stores"
- it has a meta field `nearby-cities (repeater)`
- each nearby-cities entry has `city-name` and `distance` repeater fields
- I also have a Posts Query "Stores near San Francisco", where I want to display stores near San Francisco ordered by `distance` from the `nearby-cities` -> `distance` where `city-name` equals "San Francisco".
- I am able to successfully filter by San Francisco using Tax Query (see image)
- Order by has "Order by numeric meta value", "Order by string meta value", and "Order by meta clause", which I suspect could be helpful, but cannot figure out how.

**Problem**: I can't figure out how to order by my value from the repeater.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress StackExchange! Unfortunately, questions exclusively regarding 3rd party plugins are [considered off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and better asked using their respective support methods. Please [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more. A better place to ask this type of question may be [The Official WordPress Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/forums/) or the [plugin-specific support](https://support.crocoblock.com/support/home/).

Comment: JetEngine support told me "as of now, there is no possibility to query or order items by repeater values".

Comment: Arman, if the developer of the plugin is tell you it can't be done, that's a pretty good indication that it can't.  :-(  Your best at this point would be to ditch JetEngine (so you don't have to combat the other developers decisions) and write up your own custom post type.

Comment: Do you know if I can write a shortcode that could pass in the data sorted how I want it to be sorted into the post? Kind of like this, but I'd also like to pass in data to it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56485/how-to-display-html-in-a-shortcode/64357